# How do you get the length of a binary in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

How to you get the length of a binary in bytes? It's not a string. I don't want the number of characters. I just want to know how many bytes long it is.

Comment: ```byte_size(<<0>>)```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could leverage `byte_size` for that purpose as documented [here](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#byte_size/1)

> Returns the number of bytes needed to contain bitstring.
>
> That is, if the number of bits in bitstring is not divisible by 8, the
>   resulting number of bytes will be rounded up (by excess). This
>   operation happens in constant time.
>
> Allowed in guard tests. Inlined by the compiler.
>
> **Examples**
>
> iex> byte_size(<<433::16, 3::3>>) 3
>
> iex> byte_size(<<1, 2, 3>>)

Comment: Allowed in guard tests! Even better.